# Non-recursive algorithms for ordered traversing

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, computer-science

There is a family of combinatorial algorithms, based on following technique - we observe some property of the structure and, using that property, traversing then all possible/accessible variants in linear (or closed to, whatever, doesn't really matters) time, without recursion.

Examples

**lexicographic permutation a[1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0013JLRH2) .. a[n]**

- find last a[k] such that a[k] < a[k + 1] > ...
- find the minimal a[m] in a[k + 1] .. a[n] such that a[k] < a[m]
- swap a[m] and a[k]
- revert a[k + 1] .. a[n]

**k-subsets of n**

- iterate from the end, find first zero, preceded by 1 (first a[k]==0 such that a[k + 1] == 1)
- assign a[k] = 1
- count 1's in a[k] .. a[n]
- rebalance - assign as much 1's at the end as it possible, the rest set to zero

**partitions of n (in descending order)**

- find first k such that a[k] > a[k + 1] (k = 1 also is ok)
- increase a[k] = a[k] + 1
- find sum of elements from k to the last one
- increase left neighbors by 1 as long as sum allows.

I guess, this is enough to illustrate the nature of such algorithms. These, and some other examples can be found in excellent, superb book "[Algorithms and Programming: Problems and Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0013JLRH2)".

My question is following. Can you, please, describe me more examples, in any area, of such algorithms. It would bee great if you also provide the algorithm itself (in words, like above, is preferable). References to the books, articles are also welcome. References to related theoretical issues are also welcome (for example, I just don't have a feeling when such algorithms can be builded and when  - not).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is impossibly open-ended.  You're just asking for a random list of algorithms that can be both recursive and non-recursive, right?  That doesn't seem like a very good question.  There's no "acceptable" answer to this, is there?

Comment: @S.Lott, disagree, I'm asking for algorithms for non-recursove traversal of some combinatorial structures. It something which could be tagged big-list, but I just don't have a privilege to create tags. If there will be, say, 10-15 different examples, it already would be great. In any case, this is more specific than (not closed) questions about hidden features of language X, interesting book and so on. In this sense it is way, way less open-ended.

Comment: "some combinatorial structures"?  You mean a list of numbers?  That's not a restriction in any way.  This is not any more specific than a "hidden features" question, since there is no constraint and no way for anyone to determine what answer would be "accepted".  It's just a "list of random facts" question.

Answer (score 2):

Consider an algorithm A from a family of algorithms. Either A is already iterative, or if it is recursive, it can be transformed into an equivalent iterative algorithm by simulating the calling stack by an explicit data structure. See e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Recursion_versus_iteration).

Comment: are those algorithms recursive and linear non-recursive are exactly equivalent? For example, off the top of my head, linear recursive partition is not so obvious.

Comment: The recursive and the transformed iterative algorithms are exactly equivalent: they produce the same result and have the same time/space complexity. The practical difference is that the iterative algorithms are usually faster for a given `n` than the recursive algorithms at the cost of elegance.

Comment: @Jiri, I don't see why they are all O(n). e.g. there are n! permutations, it seems that any algorithm that produce all of them will be Ω((n/e)^n)

Comment: @Max: Thank you for your comment. I thaught that he is interested in some linear algorithms to traverse (or generate) e.g. one such permutation. He writes "traversing then all possible/accessible variants in linear ... time." Now, after reading his question again and again I am no longer sure what the question is about. The quintessence of my answer is
"every recursion algorithm can be transformed to an equivalent iterative algorithm". And this is valid for any time complexity O(...). In order to avoid further confusions I am trimming my answer to this basic statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is along the same lines as Jiri's answer, but perhaps a little more direct: any solvable computational problem is solvable by a Turing machine, and I don't think anyone would describe the functioning as a Turing machine as "recursive", but as state-based. In other words, given enough auxiliary tape storage, a while loop and a select-case (or equivalent branching, e.g., if/else, construct), you can solve any problem - including these enumeration problems - using a state-machine based approach.

For instance, it is fairly straightforward to define a state-based algorithm for doing an in-order traversal of a binary search tree.

1. Begin in state DL (for down-left). If you're in DL and if the node has a left child, move down to it and stay in the state DL; otherwise, print the node's content and if the node has a right child, change to the state DR and move to the right child; if the node has no right child, change to the state UR and move to the parent.
2. If in the state DR, and you have a left child, move to the left child and change to he state DL. Otherwise, if you have a right child, print the node's contents and move to the child and stay in DR. Otherwise, move to the parent node and change to the state UL.
3. If in the state UR, print the node information and if there is a right child, move to it and change the state to DR; otherwise, move to the parent and stay in UR.
4. If in the state UL, if the current node is the right child of its parent, stay in UL and move to the parent; otherwise, if the current node is not a right child of the parent, and it is a left child, change to the state UR and move to the parent. If this node has no parent, terminate the algorithm.

Anyway, you get the idea. Ordered tree traversals are about as inherently recursive as you get; many (all?) other traversal problems can be couched in terms of traversing some tree, and here is a method for doing an inorder traversal in linear time using a state-machine. Do you believe that this method is O(n)? Hint: it visits each node no more than three times.

Comment: can you give me a hint about what books I can read on the topic. I've read about algorithms quite a lot, and still have not feeling I'm seeing the whole picture.

Comment: SUre. Perhaps what you would enjoy are some books on the theory of computation. While most "algorithms" books assume e.g. the von Neumann RAM model of computation, books on the theory of computation will usually take more varied approaches and try to demonstrate what problems can be solved by what kinds of formal mechanisms... which sounds to be more in line with what you want. Look for books on the following topics: formal language theory, automata theory, lambda calculus. Explore all levels of the Chomsky hierarchy - both grammars and automata. I can recommend specific books, too...